# How to get Rally user ObjectId?

Tags: rally

I know the [rally api](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user) and using it i can get rally user object id but it requires username and password. i don't know the password for other users. So is there any way to get the rally user object id for other user when the password is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The user endpoint you linked to is a little special in that it always just gives you back yourself.  If you instead hit the users (plural) endpoint this will behave as you are expecting and return all the users.  You can query and sort these results the same way you would with any WSAPI endpoint.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/users
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Your reply was very helpful.